# Boolean checks in underscore templates

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, boolean-logic, underscore.js-templating

I had to replace the default underscore teplating delimiters/Interpolate regex for compatibility with asp.net webforms.From the website i opted for mustache like syntax

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

tried this

`_.template("{{if(loggedIn)Welcome {{name}}}}",{name:"James",completed:true});`

but seems this is not the way( since a error occurred) to check boolean expression using a templating system. But from the docs seems it is possible

> as well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with <% … %>

- So how do i execute arbitrary js code with the above mentioned interpolation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that you're defining a Mustache-style replacement for `<%= ... %>` but trying to use it where you'd normally use `<% ... %>`. From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Define an **interpolate** regex to match expressions that should be interpolated verbatim, an **escape** regex to match expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an **evaluate** regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without insertion into the resulting string.

So there are three regexes in play:

1. **interpolate** is for `<%= ... %>`.
2. **escape** is for `<%- ... %>`.
3. **evaluate** is for `<% ... %>`.

You're telling Underscore to use `{{ ... }}` in place of `<%= ... %>` and then you're getting an error because `if(loggedIn)` can't be interpolated. You just need to fix your `_.templateSettings` to reflect what you're trying to do:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate:    /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

and then your template would look like this:

```
{{ if(loggedIn) { }}Welcome {{= name }} {{ } }}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RwgVg/8/

You'll need to include the `{` and `}` in the template because `_.template` adds semicolons when compiling the template, that results in things like:

```
if(loggedIn) {; ...
```

(Thanks to [JaredMcAteer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577926/jaredmcateer) for pointing this out).

You might want to add an **escape** regex as well, that would probably be `/\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g`.

Comment: This is probably the best explanation of Underscore's templateSettings that I've been able to find.  Their website's explanation leaves much to be desired...

Comment: Just a note your fiddle displays `Welcome James` regardless if `loggedIn` is `true` or `false` adding braces before and after `{{ if(loggedIn) { }}Welcome {{= name }}{{}}}` fixes it. Not very readable though.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer: Seems you're right, `_.template` is slipping a `;` into the compiled version so it says `if(loggedIn);...` (you can `console.log(_.template($('#tmpl').html()).source)` to see it). I'll fix this up. And yes, all those braces to get to be a bit much.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this works for the transition to the mustache style syntax:

```
/**
     * @configuration transform Underscore.js template syntax
     * @description change the Ruby on Rails style syntax to the Mustache syntax
     * @default <%= var %>
     * @modified 
     *  evaluate        {{ JavaScript code}}    execute arbitrary js code, such as loops
     *  interpolate     {{= variable }}         prints value of variables
     *  escape          {{- variable }}         this syntax will html escape variables
     */ 
    _.templateSettings = {
        evaluate:    /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,          
        interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
        escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
    };
```

This would be mustache style syntax, but keeps the original options of using the "=" and the "-".  Not using either evaluates JS, such as for loops.  One could swap them around so that the {{var}} was the interpolate and the evaluate could be something else, to keep your templates cleaner if you prefer, since interpolate is most frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you hasn't overwritten the [Underscore.templateSettings.evaluate](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L938-942) setting you should still can use: `<% ... %>` for evaluate code.

I have seen attempts to also define the `Underscore.templateSettings.evaluate` setting to match with Mustache syntax but Mustache fights very strong against *template evaluations* so is gonna be difficult.

Comment: hmm so using a dedicated templating library is best i got to do :)

Comment: If you really want Mustache, then without a doubt you need use a dedicated templating library. But remember the origin of this thread was your need of "execute arbitrary js code" in your templates and Mustache is not gonna like this :).. although Mustache is very friendly with simple _boolean_ blocks.

Comment: Yeah, i am not going to hijack the post. I will look for solution until this gets answered!! Surprisingly this too does not work. hmm seems i am doing something terribly wrong here `_.template("<% if(completed)Welcome <%= name%>%>",{name:"James",completed:true});`

Comment: I have found how it works , you have to do below `_.template("<% if(completed){ %>Welcome <%= name%><% } %>",{name:"James",completed:false});`