# how to get underscore template using mustache style to recognize an if statement

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, ejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boolean checks in underscore templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597480/boolean-checks-in-underscore-templates)

I can't use standard ERB style templates with underscore since they are being used in an express ejs file, so I changed underscore templates to use mustache style templating

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

However it now trips over the if statements, how would I change this ERB style

```
<% if (something) { %>
```

into something that works with an alternative templating in underscore

```
{{ if (something) }}
```

doesn't seem to work and I can't use the standard <% erb style since that conflicts with the ejs template that it's in.

Comment: yup it is a duplicate. will close. thanks.

Comment: FYI, I found a problem with the answer of that question and added a note to it.